# Read sql row or field in chucks

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql, odbc

I have a MSSQL database that stores files in an image field (it wasn't me!). I wrote a script that reads this field in PHP using ODBC and outputs the file directly to the browser.

```
$conn = odbc_connect( $dsn, $user, $pass );

// setting this higher will hit the PHP memory limit
// I could set this higher but the files could be too large for RAM
// Looking for an alternative that will work for any size file
odbc_longreadlen( 0 , 100000000 );

$result = odbc_exec( $conn, "SELECT imageField FROM filesTable;" );
$file = odbc_fetch_array( $result );

// File type and name
header( "Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" );
header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=spreadsheet.xlsx" );

// Disable caching
header( "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" ); // HTTP 1.1
header( "Pragma: no-cache" ); // HTTP 1.0
header( "Expires: 0" ); // Proxies

odbc_close( $conn );

die( $file['imageField'] );
```

My problem is for certain files I am running out of memory in PHP. I could raise the limit but I am wondering if there is a better way. This works as long as the files are smaller than 100000000 bytes. I want a solution that works for any size.

Is it possible to read rows or fields in chucks? My idea is to read in the chucks and output them to a temp file on disk, then send that to the user.

Comment: All things are possible. Share what you have tried.

Comment: Use limit in the sql statement. So `LIMIT 0, 1000` (first 1000). Do all the actions on that set and then `LIMIT 1000, 1000` (so the next 1000). Do this in a while loop so it continues while the query returns results. If you want people to give you a full answer then you should add what you have already tried. People will be more inclined to help you.

Comment: @Jeroen LIMIT will give me a certain number of rows. My problem is a single row (actually field) is too large for PHP to handle efficiently.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I can't find anything about retrieving less then a whole row from SQL. I am wondering if that is even possible. I was thinking I could the SPLIT function in sql but that would still give me the same amount of data, just in multiple columns.

Comment: A minimal amount of Googling turned up [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/194975).

Comment: @JayBlanchard I was looking for a way to do this using PHP or SQL.